# Single Processing Unit and Multiple Users

Tags: thin-client, multiuser

How can build system with Windows 7 using a single Processing Unit (Probabluly normal CPU or Intel NUC with i5) on which 5 or more users can use it simultaniously?
So there going to be one one CPU and 5 or more Moniters, Keyboards and Mouse, so every user front on each computer can do his own work..
I want to use it in a school in a village in India to teach basic things about computer and so wanted it to be cost effective..
If it is not possible with above hardware, please suggest alternative ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easily. In my opinion, you're unlikely to be able to get the cost/performance/multiseatedness that you want. In short, there's no way to do this.

There's a few elements here - 'Desktop' windows only lets you run a single user at a time (windows server will let you run more sessions at significantly greater cost), windows dosen't work multiheader (and the NUC dosen't really have enough ports), and well, most of the options I can think of probably suck, or are more expensive.

If you *arn't* tied into windows, you could probably use something like a raspberry pi or other low cost, small form factor single board computer- either as a standalone system (Raspberry Pis seem perfect, other than the lack of VGA ports - you need a HDMI or composite capable display or a converter. Even then, you can get 4-5 pis for the price of a *low end* nuc). There's also multiseat linux setups, but between needing multiple video outputs, and so on, not worth the effort. Get cheap, get lots, and get going.

The fundamentals of learning to *use* a computer carry forward completely well between OSes, get them started on linux, then if needed, they can probably pick up windows fairly easily (I went the other way myself).

Comment: Thanks for the help.. First I was considering doing it on Ubuntu but multiple o/p video cards and other things made the price over the budget. Risspberry Pi is good option.. Thanks for suggestion..

Comment: Just to explain.. The reason why I was thinking of Windows at 1st place is, most of the offices, colleges, exam centres and many other places only uses Windows. Even the Government Course for computer learning in State Maharashtra which must do course for getting a job or to certify your cimputer skills is supportive of windows. The course is named MSCIT ran by MKCL Organisation of state and teach only windows OS and Office. Even though it is a basic course the thing they are doing with this is forcing students learn only Windows and increase selling of MS products..

Comment: Most people are non-experimenting type so even if I teach them linux most will think it is useless or waste of time as they have to use Windows as their job place or office or home..